# HOA building a Community pool which I don’t want

Tags: hoa

I’ve lived in my neighborhood for 9 years And pay HOA dues
I have a pool
The HOA is now wanting to build a Community pool and raise our fees.
I would not have built here if they had had a Community pool because I planned my own pool.  Can they make me pay for a pool I will never use. Or do they have to let me opt out because pool dues were not in my Original restrictions and fees

Comment: That depends on what you've signed.

Comment: Also the circumstances and the timing thereof can be relevant enough to outweigh (i.e., on equitable grounds) the applicable clauses. For instance, did you need approval from the Community for building your pool? could the Community reasonably have alerted you --and failed to do so-- about its plans on building a community pool? You might want to supplement your description.

Answer (score 3):

### This is the problem with democracy

Sometimes you lose the vote and have to do things you don't want.